Spring Boot Application Fails to Start Due to "Not a managed type" Error for JPA Entity
I am working on a Spring Boot application that uses Spring Data JPA. My application fails to start, throwing an error related to one of my JPA entities. The error message is as follows:
Error creating bean with name 'membershipRepository' defined in cn.dineeasy.repository.MembershipRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on DineeasyBackendApplicationMain: Not a managed type: class cn.dineeasy.model.Membership


What I have tried:
I have verified that the @Entity annotation is present on the Membership class.
I ensured that the Membership class is in the same package (or a subpackage) as the main application class annotated with @SpringBootApplication.
I checked the database table mapping and column names, and they match the annotations in the entity class.
I also made sure that all dependencies are correctly included in the pom.xml file.
Key parts of my code:
Membership.java:
package cn.dineeasy.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "memberships")
public class Membership {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "membership_id")
    private Long membershipId;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "level_id")
    private MembershipLevel level;

    @Column(name = "expiry_date")
    private LocalDateTime expiryDate;

    @Column(name = "create_time")
    private LocalDateTime createTime;

    @Column(name = "update_time")
    private LocalDateTime updateTime;

    // Getters and Setters
}


MembershipLevel.java:
package cn.dineeasy.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "membership_levels")
public class MembershipLevel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "level_id")
    private Long levelId;

    @Column(name = "level_name")
    private String levelName;

    @Column(name = "benefits")
    private String benefits;

    // Getters and Setters
}


Error Log:
Error creating bean with name 'membershipRepository': Not a managed type: class cn.dineeasy.model.Membership

Question:
What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it? Are there any additional configurations or checks that I should perform to ensure that the Membership entity is correctly managed by JPA?
Additional Context:
The project is a Spring Boot application with the following dependencies:
Spring Boot 3.3.2
Spring Data JPA
MySQL
The application runs on Java 17.

provide repository code

And if none of those answers help, add your MembershipRepository code.

Can you check if adding @EntityScan("cn.dineeasy.model") works ?

Messing around with dependencies (following an old tutorial with newer versions introduced yourself)? Change javax.persistence to jakarta.persistence. Remove any persistence-api of direct hibernate dependency you have and include only spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.
